# Socket.IO-Client-Swiftのビルド時のエラーについて

Tags: swift, socket.io

Xcode8.3.3、Swift3でリアルタイムチャットアプリを作ろうとしているのですが、
Socket.IO-Client-Swiftをimportしてビルドしようとしたところ、
下のようなエラー・ワーニングが発生してしまいます。
（ソースはpod installで持って来ました）

```
・error
/Users/jip/Documents/Realtime_Chat_App-master/Client/chat/Pods/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Source/SocketIOClientConfiguration.swift:28:62: 'Generator' has been renamed to 'Iterator'
/Users/jip/Documents/Realtime_Chat_App-master/Client/chat/Pods/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Source/SocketIOClientConfiguration.swift:25:15: Type 'SocketIOClientConfiguration' does not conform to protocol 'Collection'
/Users/jip/Documents/Realtime_Chat_App-master/Client/chat/Pods/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Source/SocketIOClientConfiguration.swift:25:15: Type 'SocketIOClientConfiguration' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'
/Users/jip/Documents/Realtime_Chat_App-master/Client/chat/Pods/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Source/SocketIOClientConfiguration.swift:25:15: Type 'SocketIOClientConfiguration' does not conform to protocol '_IndexableBase'
/Users/jip/Documents/Realtime_Chat_App-master/Client/chat/Pods/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Source/SocketIOClient.swift:80:23: Expression type 'SocketIOClientConfiguration' is ambiguous without more context
/Users/jip/Documents/Realtime_Chat_App-master/Client/chat/Pods/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Source/SocketEngine.swift:86:23: Expression type 'SocketIOClientConfiguration' is ambiguous without more context

・warning
/Users/jip/Documents/Realtime_Chat_App-master/Client/chat/Pods/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Source/WebSocket.swift:627:64: String interpolation produces a debug description for an optional value; did you mean to make this explicit?       
/Users/jip/Documents/Realtime_Chat_App-master/Client/chat/Pods/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Source/WebSocket.swift:674:21: Will never be executed
/Users/jip/Documents/Realtime_Chat_App-master/Client/chat/Pods/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Source/SocketAnyEvent.swift:31:57: String interpolation produces a debug description for an optional value; did you mean to make this explicit?
```

[image: Xcodeの画面イメージはこんな感じです。]

どなたか原因や解決法をご存知ないでしょうか？？

Comment: ソースコードやエラーメッセージは画像ではなく、テキストとしてご質問本文に含めてくださるようにお願いします。テキストであれば検索にも乗りやすく、コピペしてその一部または全部を再利用することが簡単にできます。

Comment: ご質問の編集ありがとうございます。とりあえず、分かる範囲の情報を回答として書き込ませていただきますので、後ほどご確認ください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

一番最初のエラーメッセージに **socket.io swift**を付加して、「socket.io swift 'Generator' has been renamed to 'Iterator'」で検索したところ、以下のGitHubのissue記事が引っかかりました。

[xcode 8.3 not compiling. Solution. #614](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/issues/614)

記事中の書き込みによると、socket.ioの最新版はXcode 8.3に対応しているものの、Podでインストールしている場合、古いバージョンがインストールされてしまった人がいるようです。インストールの方法や設定を見直して、最新版がインストールされるようにすれば解消されると思われます。確認して見てください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。ご指摘のとおりバージョンが古かったようです。podfileに最新のバージョン指定の記述を足してやり直してみたら解消しました。